# Compare Records in Single SQL Table

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL 2008 R2

I have a table that contains Windows security event log entries. The possible event ID's are 560, 562 and 564.

These are the three event log entries created when a user deletes a file.

The 560 contains most of the data regarding the user who performed the delete, the source IP, the file name, etc. However, the 560 is not the event that confirms the delete occurred. The 560 is the object open event type.

When a user deletes a file the 560 (object open) is created first, then a 562 (handle closed) and finally a 564 (object delete).

The common link between all three of these events is the Handle ID. So for a single delete you'll have something similar to the following:

```
EventID HandleID UserName              Event            File
564     000015f7 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM   Object Delete    N/A
562     000015f7 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM   Handle Closed    N/A
560     000015f7 DOMAIN\USER           Object Open      \share\filename
```

I would like UserName and File from 560 event but only when there's a 564 w/ the same HandleID.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to do it.  You could use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT UserName, File
FROM EventTableNameNotProvided e1
WHERE e1.EventID = 560
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM EventTableNameNotProvided e2
        WHERE e2.HandleID = e1.HandleID
            AND e2.EventID = 564)
```

Or a self JOIN:

```
SELECT e1.UserName, e1.File
FROM EventTableNameNotProvided e1
JOIN EventTableNameNotProvided e2
    ON e2.HandleID = e1.HandleID
WHERE e1.EventID = 560
    AND e2.EventID = 564
```

Either or both queries might be more useful with a `SELECT DISTINCT`.  It depends on your data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT UserName, File
FROM YourTable
WHERE EventID = 560
  AND HandleID IN (
    SELECT HandleID 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE EventID = 564
  )
```